# Hough Circle detction AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'rint'

Tags: python, image, numpy, opencv, image-processing

I am trying to detect this circle using Houghcircle in open cv2, but am getting an error.

[image]

below is my code

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ebQBB.jpg)

```
chh = cv2.HoughCircles(crr, cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1,minDist = 50, param1 =200, 
param2 = 18, minRadius = 20, maxRadius =60)
```

[2]

```
ch = np.uint16(np.around(ch)) #error appears to come from here
```

Am assuming the [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ebQBB.jpg) finds the circles while [2] converts it into an array,am suspecting `np.around`.

An explanation would be greatly valued.
Kind regards.

full error:

> AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
>   C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\fromnumeric.py in _wrapfunc(obj, method, *args, **kwds)
>        55     try:
>   ---> 56         return getattr(obj, method)(*args, **kwds)
>        57
>
> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'round'
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
>    in 
>   ----> 1 ch = np.uint16(np.around(ch)) #error appears to come from here
>
> C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\fromnumeric.py in around(a, decimals, out)
>      3005 
>      3006     """
>   -> 3007     return _wrapfunc(a, 'round', decimals=decimals, out=out)
>      3008 
>      3009
>
> C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\fromnumeric.py in _wrapfunc(obj, method, *args, **kwds)
>        64     # a downstream library like 'pandas'.
>        65     except (AttributeError, TypeError):
>   ---> 66         return _wrapit(obj, method, *args, **kwds)
>        67 
>        68
>
> C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\fromnumeric.py in _wrapit(obj, method, *args, **kwds)
>        44     except AttributeError:
>        45         wrap = None
>   ---> 46     result = getattr(asarray(obj), method)(*args, **kwds)
>        47     if wrap:
>        48         if not isinstance(result, mu.ndarray):
>
> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'rint'

Comment: `ch` in [2] is not defined. You are creating `chh` in [1]

Comment: sorry, i still would get the same error if i insert 'chh' in the second code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a simple example to perform circle detection using [`cv2.HoughCircles`](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_houghcircles/py_houghcircles.html)

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Load image, grayscale, Otsu's threshold
image = cv2.imread('1.jpg')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

# Find circles with HoughCircles
circles = cv2.HoughCircles(thresh, cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1, minDist=150, param1=200, param2=18, minRadius=20)

# Draw circles
if circles is not None:
    circles = np.round(circles[0, :]).astype("int")
    for (x,y,r) in circles:
        cv2.circle(image, (x,y), r, (36,255,12), 3)

cv2.imshow('thresh', thresh)
cv2.imshow('image', image)
cv2.waitKey()
```

[image]
[image]